# Why do I keep getting a NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, file, exception

This is the code I currently have. For some reason, I keep getting and error called: NoSuchElementException: No line found. The exception occurs at the line:
`"String number = scanPhone.nextLine();"` 
 and in the Provider class and at the line:
`"provObj.readCellPhoneFile(fileNameIn);"`
in the CellPhonesPart2 class. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Provider {
   private String name;
   private CellPhone[] phones;
   private String[] excludedRecords;

   /**
    * Constructor for Provider class.
    */
   public Provider() {
      name = "not yet assigned";
      phones = new CellPhone[0];
      excludedRecords = new String[0];
   }

   /**
    * Reads in file name and assigns data.
    *
    * @param fileNameIn Input for file name from main
    * @throws IOException from scanning file name
    */
   public void readCellPhoneFile(String fileNameIn) throws IOException {
      //Reads in file name and creates Scanner object
      File fileIn = new File(fileNameIn);
      Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(fileIn);
      //Assigns name from first line
      name = scanFile.nextLine();
      //Assigns data from file to different categories
      while (scanFile.hasNext()) {
         Scanner scanPhone = new Scanner(scanFile.nextLine());
         scanPhone.useDelimiter(", *");

         String phoneType = scanPhone.nextLine();
         char phoneChar = phoneType.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

         //Assigns phone to different category
         switch (phoneChar) {   
            case 'F':
               String number = scanPhone.nextLine();
               int texts = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               int minutes = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               FlipPhone flip1 = new FlipPhone(number, texts, minutes);
               addPhone(flip1);
               break;
            case 'S':
               number = scanPhone.nextLine();
               texts = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               minutes = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               int data = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               SmartPhone smart1 = new SmartPhone(number, texts, minutes, data);
               addPhone(smart1);
               break;
            case 'I':
               number = scanPhone.nextLine();
               texts = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               minutes = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               data = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               int iMessages = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               IPhone iPhone1 = new IPhone(number, texts,
                  minutes, data, iMessages);
               addPhone(iPhone1);
               break;
            case 'A':
               number = scanPhone.nextLine();
               texts = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               minutes = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               data = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               int hotspotMin = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.nextLine());
               Android android1 = new Android(number, texts,
                  minutes, data, hotspotMin);
               addPhone(android1);
               break;
            default:
               String unrecognized = scanPhone.nextLine();
               addExcludedRecord(unrecognized);   
         }
      }   
   }

   /**
    * Returns string for provider name.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   /**
    * Assigns a name input as provider name.
    *
    * @param nameIn Input for provider name
    */
   public void setName(String nameIn) {
      name = nameIn;
   }

   /**
    * Returns CellPhone array for phones.
    *
    * @return CellPhone[]
    */
   public CellPhone[] getPhones() {
      return phones;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string array for excluded records.
    *
    * @return String[]
    */
   public String[] getExcludedRecords() {
      return excludedRecords;
   }

   /**
    * Adds phone to array of phones.
    *
    * @param newPhoneIn Input for phone object
    */
   public void addPhone(CellPhone newPhoneIn) {
      //Increases size of phones array
      CellPhone[] newPhones = new CellPhone[phones.length + 1];
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         newPhones[i] = phones[i];
      }
      phones = newPhones;
      //Adds CellPhone object to phones array
      phones[phones.length] = newPhoneIn;
   }

   /**
    * Determines if phone number is found and deleted.
    *
    * @return boolean
    * @param numberIn Input for phone number
    */
   public boolean deletePhone(String numberIn) {
      boolean delete = false;
      int deleteIndex = -1;
      //Searches for phone number match
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         if (numberIn == phones[i].getNumber()) {
            deleteIndex = i;
            //Decreases size of phones array
            CellPhone[] newPhones = new CellPhone[phones.length - 1];
            for (i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
               newPhones[i] = phones[i];
            }
            phones = newPhones;
         }
      }   
      if (deleteIndex > -1) {
         for (int i = deleteIndex; i < phones.length - 1; i++) {
            phones[i] = phones[i + 1];
         }
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Adds unrecognized phone to excluded records.
    *
    * @param excRecIn Input for unrecognized phone
    */
   public void addExcludedRecord(String excRecIn) {
      //Increases capacity of excludedRecords
      String[] newExcRecords = new String[excludedRecords.length + 1];
      for (int i = 0; i < excludedRecords.length; i++) {
         newExcRecords[i] = excludedRecords[i];
      }
      excludedRecords = newExcRecords;
      //Adds excRecIn to array
      excludedRecords[excludedRecords.length] = excRecIn;
   }

   /**
    * Returns list of cell phones in phones array.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      for (CellPhone phone : phones) {
         result += phone;
      }
      return result;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total bill for all phones.
    *
    * @return double
    */
   public double calculateTotalBill() {
      double totalBill = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         totalBill += phones[i].calculateBill();
      }   
      return totalBill;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total number of texts for all phones.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public int calculateTotalTexts() {
      int totalTexts = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         totalTexts += phones[i].getTexts();
      }   
      return totalTexts;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total number of minutes for all phones.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public int calculateTotalMinutes() {
      int totalMinutes = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         totalMinutes += phones[i].getMinutes();
      }   
      return totalMinutes;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total data for smartphones.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public int calculateTotalData() {
      int totalData = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         if (phones[i] instanceof SmartPhone) {
            totalData += ((SmartPhone) phones[i]).getData();
         }   
      }   
      return totalData;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total hotspot minutes for Androids.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public int calculateTotalHotspotMin() {
      int totalHotspotMin = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         if (phones[i] instanceof Android) {
            totalHotspotMin += ((Android) phones[i]).getHotspotMin();
         }   
      }   
      return totalHotspotMin;
   }

   /**
    * Calculates total iMessage count for iPhones.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public int calculateTotalIMessages() {
      int totalIMessages = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
         if (phones[i] instanceof IPhone) {
            totalIMessages += ((IPhone) phones[i]).getIMessages();
         }   
      }   
      return totalIMessages;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string for summary report.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String summary() {
      String summary = "------------------------------"
         + "\nSummary for " + getName()
         + "\n------------------------------"
         + "\nNumber of cell phones: " + getPhones()
         + "Texts: " + calculateTotalTexts()
         + "Talk Minutes: " + calculateTotalMinutes()
         + "Data: " + calculateTotalData()
         + "Hotspot Minutes: " + calculateTotalHotspotMin()
         + "iMessages: " + calculateTotalIMessages()
         + "Bill Total: $" + calculateTotalBill()
         + "\n\n------------------------------"
         + "\nRates for " + getName()
         + "\n------------------------------"
         + rates()
         + "\n------------------------------"
         + "\nCell Phones by Number"
         + "\n------------------------------\n"
         + listByNumber()
         + "\n------------------------------"
         + "\nCell Phones by Billing Amount"
         + "\n------------------------------\n"
         + listByBill()
         + "\n------------------------------"
         + "\nExcluded Records"
         + "\n------------------------------\n"
         + excludedRecordsList();
      return summary;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string for different rates.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String rates() {
      String rates = "FlipPhone Talk Rate: $" + FlipPhone.TALK_RATE
         + "\tText Rate: $" + FlipPhone.TEXT_RATE
         + "SmartPhone Talk Rate: $" + SmartPhone.TALK_RATE
         + "\tText Rate: $" + SmartPhone.TEXT_RATE
         + "\tMax Talk Time: " + SmartPhone.MAX_TALK_TIME
         + "\n\tiPhone iMessage Rate: $" + IPhone.IMESSAGE_RATE
         + "\n\tAndroid HotspotRate: $" + Android.HOTSPOT_RATE;
      return rates;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string of phones sorted by number.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String listByNumber() {
      String listByNumber = "";
      for (CellPhone phone : phones) {
         listByNumber += phone.toString();
      }
      Arrays.sort(phones);
      return listByNumber;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string of phones sorted by bill.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String listByBill() {
      String listByBill = "";
      for (CellPhone phone : phones) {
         listByBill += phone.toString();
      }
      Arrays.sort(phones, new CellPhoneBillComparator());
      return listByBill;
   }

   /**
    * Returns string excluded records.
    *
    * @return String
    */
   public String excludedRecordsList() {
      String excRecList = "";
      for (String phone : excludedRecords) {
         excRecList += phone;
      }
      return excRecList;
   }
}
```

It reads in the file from this class:

```
public class CellPhonesPart2 {

   /** 
    * Creates objects from different classes and prints objects. 
    *
    * @param args Reads in file
    * @throws IOException from scanning input file
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String fileNameIn = args[0];
      Provider provObj = new Provider();
      provObj.readCellPhoneFile(fileNameIn);

      System.out.println(provObj.summary());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner scanPhone = new Scanner(scanFile.nextLine());
// this is causing your error. scanPhone is ultimately just a one line String

// this line will be found
String phoneType = scanPhone.nextLine();

// this line won't because scanPhone is only one line
String number = scanPhone.nextLine();
```

**Edit: possible Solution**

```
 while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
     Scanner scanPhone = new Scanner(scanFile.nextLine());
     scanPhone.useDelimiter(", *");

     String phoneType = scanPhone.next();
     char phoneChar = phoneType.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

     //Assigns phone to different category
     switch (phoneChar) {   
        case 'F':
           String number = scanPhone.next();
           int texts = Integer.parseInt(scanePhone.next());
           int minutes = Integer.parseInt(scanPhone.next());
           FlipPhone flip1 = new FlipPhone(number, texts, minutes);
           addPhone(flip1);
           break;
```

Changed all the `scanPhone.nextLine()`'s to `scanPhone.next()`

Also, try using `while (scanFile.hasNextLine());` instead of `hasNext()`

Comment: The directions want me to have two Scanner objects: "A cell phone line is read in, a second scanner is created on the line, and individual values for the cell phone are read in." But I deleted the scanPhone, and now it has a line, but it's giving me a NumberFormatException. It may be the order of the code, but what would you say is the problem now?

Comment: I'm not sure what eaxactly you're tyring to do but if you delete this line `String phoneType = scanPhone.nextLine();` You won't get the error anymore.

Comment: You have to remember, since `Scanner scanPhone = new Scanner(scanFile.nextLine());` is only one line, you can't access `nextLine()` in the same loop twice for `scanPhone`.

Comment: Is the phone name and number on the same line? If it is, there's a different solution. In your code, the assumption is that phone name and number are on two different lines.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing, you're using a delimiter. In that case, you should use `String phoneType = scanPhone.next();` and `String number = scanPhone.nextLine();`. This will work for you.

Comment: Oh, it worked this time! This was very thorough and helpful. Thanks so much! I was stuck on that problem for the longest time.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an appropriate  hasNext() before calling nextLine();
Scanner may be empty.!

Comment: Read the Scanner API Doc for the available functions.